# processing: drawing lines with delay inside loop

Tags: loops, import, delay, processing, draw

I want to display Paths from an external .txt file with data like this in it:

```
2,90,22
2,83,25
2,59,20
2,60,31
2,52,35
2,43,41
2,29,48
2,23,54
2,17,66
6,525,26
8,626,14
3,379,132
3,377,143
3,367,147
3,355,153
3,341,154
3,330,155
```

Here is the code

```
ArrayList pointList;

String[] temp;
String[] lines;

int n;
int x;
int y;
int id;


void setup(){
  lines = loadStrings("positions.txt");
  size(400,400);
  pointList = new ArrayList();

}

void draw(){
  //this is empty
}

void mouseReleased(){
  strokeWeight(9);
  importDraw();
}

void importDraw(){ 

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i)
    {

      String[] temp = split(lines[i], ',');
      int id_ = id;
      id = int(temp[0]);
      int x_ = x;
      int y_ = y;
      x = int(temp[1]);
      y = int(temp[2]);
      PVector location = new PVector(x,y);
      if (id == id_)
      { 
      if(x_-x>0) stroke(255,0,0,10); else stroke(0,0,255,10); //red lines moving left blue lines moving right
      line(x_,y_,x,y);
      }
      n++;
      del(10); // delay of 10 secs
      println("delay done" + n); // console log after delay with number of loops that passed

    }
}

void del(int t)
{
  int time = millis();
  while(millis() - time <= t);
}
```

I want the lines inbetween the points to be drawn with a delay, after some time with google i came up with the custom delay-function del(), which wont work because inside the loop no frame will happen. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: So each time you click you want the next line to be drawn? Or click once and all the lines draw with a delay between each?

Comment: Once I click I want all the lines to be drawn with delay between each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: I used noLoop to stop the draw looping and called redraw to update display. Redraw calls the draw method. Also for your del function you have del(10) commented as a 10 second delay. When in fact is 10 milliseconds. del(10000) is a 10 second delay.

```
 ArrayList pointList;

    String[] temp;
    String[] lines;

    int n;
    int x;
    int y;
    int id;
    int i; //declare i here

    boolean running; //use this to see if draw loop has terminated

    void setup(){
      lines = loadStrings("positions.txt");
      size(400,400);
      pointList = new ArrayList();
      noLoop();
      running=true;
    }

      void draw(){

       if(i < lines.length){ 
       String[] temp = split(lines[i], ',');
          int id_ = id;
          id = int(temp[0]);
          int x_ = x;
          int y_ = y;
          x = int(temp[1]);
          y = int(temp[2]);
          PVector location = new PVector(x,y);
          if (id == id_)
          { 
          if(x_-x>0) stroke(255,0,0,10); else stroke(0,0,255,10); //red lines moving left blue lines moving right
          line(x_,y_,x,y);
          }
          n++;
          println("delay done" + i); // console log after delay with number of loops that passed
          ++i;
          running=true;  //restart loop
       } 
    }

    void mouseReleased(){
      strokeWeight(22);
      i= 0;
      while(i < lines.length){
        if(running){
           println("..........." + i);
           running=false;  //stop the loop until draw completes
           redraw();
           //del(100); //set your delay
        }
      }
    }

    void del(int t)
    {
      int time = millis();
      while(millis() - time <= t);
    }
```

Comment: that works good, thank you for this nice idea! But there is still one little problem. I have a list with about 600lines of that coordinates, and your code works fine until I put my delay() under 25. Then the code just gets executed up to line 580 and stops. Now when I put down the delay even more, lets say on 15, the lines only get processed until line 430 and it stops without a warning. Do you happen to know what could be the reason? Since I want to process lists much longer in the end.. Could it be the Array that needs to be an ArrayList for such a length?

Comment: @ibanes88 no its not the Array/ArrayList. The problem appears to be with concurrency. The for loop runs too fast and doesn't wait for the draw method to finish before incrementing i. The proper solution to this would be to create threads and synchronize calls to the draw method, if you want to look into that. I have edited my solution to one that should work now with any delay speed and avoid this issue.. Albeit my solution doesn't use threads and is probably not the most elegant.

Comment: thank you a lot! It doesnt need to be the most elegant, I totally got the idea behind the problem - thats perfect!

Comment: With Processing 3.5 that program freezes. It works only after commenting out `noLoop()` but in that case it is not a solution.